# Can I change the default project settings at startup of a new project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For example, I want to always start new project with "Scripting Runtime Version" setting as ".NET 4.x Equivalent". I'm passing a series of tutorial articles right now, so it requires to start a new project each tutorial. It is very annoying always go to the tree of options to change the runtime version and - of course! - restart Unity.

Is it there defaultSettings.ini or something for Unity?

Comment: You only need to do this once. Unity should handle the rest when you restart the Editor. Change the scripting runtime once, save and restart Unity...

Comment: @PassetCronUs this works on a per project basis but I think OP wants a systemwide default startup setting for Unity.

Comment: @PassetCronUs, derHugo is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under

```
<UNITY_INSTALL_ROOT>\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\ProjectTemplates
```

you can find all the default settings for all kinds of Unity project type.

To change the `ScriptingruntimeVersion` to `.NET 4.6` e.g. you have to change

```
<UNITY_INSTALL_ROOT>\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\ProjectTemplates\com.unity.template.3d\ProjectSettings\ProjectSettings.asset
```

the line

```
scriptingRuntimeVersion: 0
```

to

```
scriptingRuntimeVersion: 1
```

---

Or simply create one new project, make all your settings and than copy

```
New Unity Project\ProjectSettings\ProjectSettings.asset
```

(and any other file you wnat to have as default) to e.g.

```
<UNITY_INSTALL_ROOT>\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\ProjectTemplates\com.unity.template.3d\ProjectSettings\
```

---

Make sure you make necessary backups before overwriting those system/Unity files. Otherwise you also can simply re-install Unity if anything goes south.

Comment: Are these default settings files rewritten after Unity update?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. I install every new Unity Version into a new folder to be more flexible if something isn't working out. So I never made an Update so far. It is very likely that with an Update come new features that require some new entries in the settings and therefore it might get overwritten with every Update and your old template might also not work if copied in again. You might have to change according lines manually every time.